# How to insert item as LAST option in a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know to add an item as the first item, I use:

```
ddlTest.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---New First Item---", "-1"));
```

I tried `-1` as the index but then I didn't even see the item. How to I add an item as the *last* item in the list without knowing its index number (because the dropdown is populated from a database)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to add to the LAST position, just add to the list as

```
ddlTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("---New First Item---", "-1"));
```

as it will append to the last place by default.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! (if you briefly saw my initial comment, it was meant for another answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size or length of the list as the index, since length is equal to last position plus one.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by adding first all the items and after that, add one based on the index. You know that once your items are in the list.

Here's some code:

```
// Fill dropdownlist with data from database.
int index = ddlTest.Items.Count;

// You don't need to add or subtract one, because count is starting from 1, while the index starts from 0. 

ddlTest.Items.Insert(index, 0, new ListItem("--- New First Item---", "-1");
```

I believe that this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `0` from your `Add` method. It will automatically detect that the item has to be added at the end.

```
ddlTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("---New First Item---", "-1"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives the error that no overloaded method for Insert takes only one argument.

Comment: Oops, used `Insert` instead of `Add`. My Bad

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("AddNew","AddNew"));

ref:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Programmatically-add-items-to-DropDownList-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx